# Javascript converting string to number in function call in MVC View

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am creating a partial view that generates a table with buttons to call a JavaScript function I have rendered in the header section.  Everything works fine except that one of the parameters of the function is a string that is composed of numbers and dashes.  An example would be 89.14-2-84.  It's an id number and I need to pass that to the JavaScript function. The MVC view code is:

```
 <input type="button" value="Select" class="btn btn-default" onclick="fcnTest( @item.key.ToString() )"/>
```

This is rendered as `onclick="fcnTest(89.14-2-84)`

When the function is called the parameter gets converted to a number doing the math so the value passed is 3.14.  What I need to do is put single quotes around @item.key.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to put quotes around it to represent it as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
onclick="fcnTest( @item.key.ToString() )"
```

With:

```
onclick="fcnTest('@item.key.ToString()')"
```

`@item.key.ToString()` will dump the *contents* of the string in your HTML / JS, *without* quotes. You need to add the quotes yourself, like this edit does.